# How to modify column values in a data frame based on previous years value in another column of the same dataframe for same company

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Please find below the input and sample output:

[image: input and output image]
If the count is null , then the next years weight becomes zero. We need to group by company and year. Please note that the starting and ending years may be different for different companies. Also if a year is missing then automatically the next available year should have zero.For e.g. def has data upto 2016 and then 2018(2017 is missing). Since 2017 is missing 2018 weight should be zero as we are assuming missing years have null values.

I have also added an image of sample input and output

Answer (score 0):

df has columns company, year, weight, count

```
flag = False
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if flag:
        row['weight'] = 0
        flag = False
    if row['count'] is None:
        flag = True
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, what you need is [pandas.DataFrame.shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html):

Assume your pandas.DataFrame is named df:

```
import numpy as np

df.sort_values(['company', 'year'], inplace=True)
is_previous_null = df.loc[:, 'count'].shift(1).isnull()  # Is the previous 'count' value null?
is_same_company = (df.loc[:, 'company'] == df.loc[:, 'company'].shift(1))  # Check if the previous row's 'company' value is the same as the current one
df.loc[is_previous_null & is_same_company, 'value'] = 0
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If a year is missing then automatically the next available year should have zero.For e.g. def has data upto 2016 and then 2018(2017 is missing). Since 2017 is missing 2018 weight should be zero as we are assuming missing years have null values. I forgot to point this out in my previous query. Please see my updated question. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solution if consecutive years per `company` - first replace missing values by helper values - e.g. `tmp`, then use [`DataFrameGroupBy.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html) and compare `tmp`.

Last set `0` by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df = df.sort_values(['company', 'year'])

mask = df.assign(count=df['count'].fillna('tmp')).groupby('company')['count'].shift().eq('tmp')

df.loc[mask, 'weight'] = 0
print (df)
  company  year  weight  count
0     abc  2016     0.7    1.0
1     abc  2017     0.3    NaN
2     abc  2018     0.0    3.0
3     def  2015     0.6    6.0
4     def  2016     0.6    NaN
5     def  2017     0.0    7.0
6     def  2018     0.7    5.0
```

EDIT:

First add new years by `reindex` per groups with minimal and maximal years:

```
s = (df.set_index('year')
      .groupby('company')['count']
      .apply(lambda x: x.reindex(np.arange(x.index.min(), x.index.max() + 1)).fillna('tmp')))
print (s)
company  year
abc      2016      1
         2017    tmp
         2018      3
def      2015      6
         2016      8
         2017    tmp
         2018      5
Name: count, dtype: object
```

Then shift like in original solution per `company`, here by first level `company` and compare by `tmp`:

```
m = s.groupby(level=0).shift().eq('tmp').rename('m')
print (m)
company  year
abc      2016    False
         2017    False
         2018     True
def      2015    False
         2016    False
         2017    False
         2018     True
Name: m, dtype: bool
```

Create mask with same index like original DataFrame with `join`:

```
mask = df.join(m, on=['company','year'])['m']
print (mask)
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
4    False
5     True
Name: m, dtype: bool
```

Set `0` values:

```
df.loc[mask, 'weight'] = 0
print (df)
  company  year  weight  count
0     abc  2016     0.7    1.0
1     abc  2017     0.3    NaN
2     abc  2018     0.0    3.0
3     def  2015     0.6    6.0
4     def  2016     0.6    8.0
5     def  2018     0.0    5.0
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @jazrael I have an additional condition which i forgot to point out.If a year is missing then automatically the next available year should have zero.For e.g. def has data upto 2016 and then 2018(2017 is missing). Since 2017 is missing 2018 weight should be zero as we are assuming missing years have null values.Kindly see my updated question for the same